# Resizing images with object-fit:contain in flexbox only works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a photo mosaic using flexbox and `object-fit: contain` by changing the line height (and thus adjusting width keeping the aspect ratio).

This works well in Firefox, however not in Chrome, iExplorer, Edge, where the images shrink in place. While the images are adjusted in size, the spacing is increased.

I made an example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o87cpeL7/6/) with the following Code where

- container is a line of images
- image1/2 are the images in a container
- img contains the actual picture

HTML

```
<div id=container class=lContainer>
  <div id=image1 class=imageThumb>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200">
  </div>
  <div id=image1 class=imageThumb>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
}

.imageThumb {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  min-width: auto;
}
```

JS (resizing the pictures to show the effect)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divID = document.getElementById('\container')
  var el = $(divID);
  curHeight = 200
  goalHeight = 150;

  el.height(curHeight).animate({
    height: goalHeight
  }, 600, function() {
    el.css('height', goalHeight);
    $(el).css("opacity", 0.99);
    console.log("done")
  });
});
```

I noticed that toggling padding on the image in Chrome yields the intended result (e.g. the page is not loaded correctly, if I toggle padding off / on in the inspector, the result changes to the intended one).

Using an online autoprefixer to account for the other browsers does not change a thing.

What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure about the Chrome issue, but `object-fit` is not supported by IE. http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: also, recently published article that may be of interest: https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the article was my base for object-fit:contain - I did overlook the support however. Turns out, that it makes no difference in IE, Edge, Firefox,  if the "object-fit:contain"-line is there or not (FF is still ok, the other two are not). However chrome gets skewed images. (See Fiddle variant [link](https://jsfiddle.net/o87cpeL7/7/))